# A JMS-Queue-Factory-Bean --> Reuse a injected jms queue in different beans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jms, hornetq

I'm using jms with jboss/wildfly (jee6).

A JMS Queue can easily be injected using:

```
@Resource(name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/queuename")
private Queue myQueue;
```

Now I'd like to implement a central Stateless Bean which gets all the queues injected and which provides a single String parameterized method to retrieve the Queue in a factory like way:

```
@Resource(name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/queuename1")
private Queue myQueue1;

@Resource(name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/queuename2")
private Queue myQueue2;

public Queue getQueueIWant(String identifier) {
  if("IdentifyingString".equals(identifier))
  { return myQueue1; }
  if...
}
```

Inside another Bean this "FactoryBean" gets injected:

```
@EJB
private MyQueueFactory queueFactory;
```

and can easily be used:

```
...
Queue queue = queueFactory.getQueueIWant("AIdentifier");
producer = session.createProducer(queue);
...
```

The retrieved Queue instance will be used to send messages to the queue (MessageProducer) and to retrieve them (MessageConsumer) in different places (Beans). I have tried this implementation and it **seems** to work.

My Question is does anyone see any Problems with this?
Could this lead to instability?
Should i use jndiLookup instead?
Is there a better/easier way?
Or is this nice and possible :-) ?

Thanks
Philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have managed to centralize the resource declration/injection, but at your usage site you still need to address each queue individually. So not much has been gained compared with direct injection.

---

It seems that you are trying to have something like an **array of queues** together with **resource injection**, but resource injection in that case does not really **scale**: Each new queue requires a deployment.

In your case I suggest using a **manual JNDI lookup** in an **iteration**. Then you can put the queues in an array/list for further processing. You could even pass the number of queues as a parameter into the method, and so the **number of queues** can be changed **dynamically** at run-time:

Pseudo-code (not tested, just for illustration):

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
Queue[] qs = new Queue[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  String name = "queue/queuename" + i;
  qs[i] = (Queue) ic.lookup(name);
}
```

---

If the queue name is based on a run-time argument (like an incoming JMS message) a JNDI lookup would be suitable, because **static resource injection** and **dynamic naming** conflicts somehow. Using a dynamic JNDI lookup scales, as a deployment to support additional queues is not required.

Comment: The redeployment would not be a problem. We are developing a core-component of an jee application. Our customer will add some custom parts but will not be able to change our code. So i have to design a "plugin"-API which enables extension of our core-components. The customer may add additional queues and use the api the define which to use, by returning a identifying String.

Comment: You add another level of complexity/indirection and a dependency, so what do you gain? You always need an ID (the resource name or another identifier), and in both cases it's a one-liner (with an annotation).

Comment: Yes, but the customer will get an api for an queue factory which my Beans get injected. And an api for a Task which will have a getIdentifier --> String method. This way my code may recieve customer tasks and send them to the customers queue. Yes this can also be done with jndi lookup. But i thought i could handle all with injection without a lookup.

Comment: So the queue name is *dynamic*, based on incoming tasks. This *conflicts* with *static resource injection*. A JNDI lookup is would be adequate.

Comment: Ok i agree. Would it then be ok to put the lookup into a stateless bean and to cache the looked-up Queues inside a static map? Or should I lookup a new Queue Instance for every caller?

Comment: Technically speaking this is possible, but the performance gain is probably minimal. A JNDI lookup is possibly a map somehow as well. If you do it statically, you have to deal with exceptions in a static initializer. I suggest using a normal JNDI lookup to be able to report exceptions along the method call. Comparing the lookup costs with actual sending ... sending is probably much more expensive.